# Vb.net and Crystal Reports adding groups and subreport

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, grouping, subreport

I have two tables, tblCI and tblCICheck

here is the link for the data on the table

[tblCI and tblCICheck](http://i1038.photobucket.com/albums/a464/Karuro_SilentSin/3_zps1b47bc85.jpg)

and this is the output for my crystal report

[Current Xtal Output](http://i1038.photobucket.com/albums/a464/Karuro_SilentSin/1_zps1fef806e.jpg)

What I wanted:

[Desired Output](http://i1038.photobucket.com/albums/a464/Karuro_SilentSin/2_zpsce1b41d6.jpg)

I have already linked the tables on their corresponding keys (license number) but still the other tables can have their data. I know I'm lacking something here, and I don't know how to search it because I don't know xtal report terms.. can somebody help me or guide me what to do? I'm really stuck here. Thanks :)

EDIT:

I got it already.

create a subreport with the report wizard

> ->new report name 
>   ->click report wizard
>   ->add the table
>   you want to display
>   ->next
>   ->add the field you want to
>   display
>   ->click finish
>   ->select Link tab
>   ->under report
>   fields, select the field    you want to link it to.
>   ->click ok,
>   then its done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a subreport with the report wizard

->new report name 
->click report wizard 
->add the table you want to display
->next
->add the field you want to display
->click finish
->select Link tab
->under report fields, select the field you want to link it to.
->click ok, then its done